# Show that each of the following is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Verify that each of the following is an isomorphism:

1) $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $T(x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z,z+x)$.

2) $T: M_{2,2} \to \mathbb{R}^4$ defined by $T\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\right) = (a+b, d, c, a-b)$.

For the 1), should we find $S: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $S(x,y,z)=(x, y, z)$ first? And in general do we have to show that each of them is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave you to check that these are actually linear transformations. However, the fact that I am about to express them as matrices implies that they are linear transformations.

---

1) We can represent $T$ by the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}_.$$

By this I mean that $T(v) = Av$.

Then $T$ is invertible if and only if $\det(A) \neq 0$.

Since $\det(A) = 2$, we have that $T$ is invertible.

---

2) Let $$e_{1,1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \  e_{1,2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \ e_{2,1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \ e_{2,2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}_.$$

These form a basis of $M_{2,2}$. If we use the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$, the matrix of this transformation becomes:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}_.$$

Since $\det(A) = 2 \neq 0$, we have that $T$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you. So since they are invertibles, are they isomorphic? I'm asking because our professor told us to find if they are one to one or onto. So I'm lost. Your reasoning looks easier.

Comment: For a linear transformation, being invertible and being an isomorphism is equivalent.